# How to add full span in content of editor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have these two functions: the first one is for when someone chooses an option from the select box in the toolbar add it to the content of the editor!

the code is working but it add `span` like this:

`<span class="text-tiny">Second Side</span>`

I want to when gose to editor become like this:

`<span class="text-tiny" id="second_side">Second Side</span>`

with id in the span

The Code

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    forms.forEach(function(item,index) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.setAttribute("value",'<span class="text-tiny" id="'+id+item.type+'">'+item.name+'</span> <span>­</span>');
        option.innerHTML = item.name;
        select.appendChild(option);
        div.appendChild(select);
    });

    select.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        insertHTMLAtCursor(editor,select.value)
    });
    
});

function insertHTMLAtCursor(id,value){
    // value = <span class="text-tiny" id="second_side">Second Side</span>
    const viewFragment = id.data.processor.toView(value);
    const modelFragment = id.data.toModel(viewFragment);
    id.model.insertContent(modelFragment, id.model.document.selection);
}
```

Comment: What's not working? Is there an error? What is it?

Comment: @code it works but, it adds to content like this `<span class="text-tiny">Second Side</span>` and I need to add `id` to span when added to content like this `<span class="text-tiny" id="second_side">Second Side</span>`

Comment: Where does the variable `id` come from? (`id+item.type`)

Comment: @code `var id = item.id ? item.id+'-' : '';`

Comment: Also by the way, you can't put HTML in inputs or it'll render as text.